# sqlmap cut last 2 symbols of MD5 hash password. Hach the box

Tags: md5, sql-injection, sqlmap, opentest

I have my blackbox machine, with sql injection. But when i try to see md5 hash of password, i got only 30 symbols. How can i fix it?

[00:13:15] [ERROR] unable to retrieve the number of columns for table 'users' in database 'test_task'
[00:13:15] [WARNING] unable to retrieve column names for table 'users' in database 'test_task'
do you want to use common column existence check? [y/N/q] y
which common columns (wordlist) file do you want to use?
[1] default 'C:\Users\OlegM\Documents\sqlmapproject-sqlmap-0d19af8\data\txt\common-columns.txt' (press Enter)
[2] custom

> 1

[2 entries]
+----+--------------------------------+--------+
| id | pass                           | name   |
+----+--------------------------------+--------+
| 1  | 79fec28cf4b1703e89b8050146f446 | admin  |
| 2  | csec{b300b2cc-7ba2-4d57}       | flag   |
+----+--------------------------------+--------+

I tried --hex and --no-cast, and it doesnot help. Also i tried to add different tampers.